# JSON to Swift 5 Object Using Codable

Tags: json, swift

I'm VERY new to Swift and have some very basic questions concerning HTTP requests, parsing JSON using Codable, passing data and storing the session token into UserDefaults. I tried multiple answers on stack overflow, but none did the trick for me.

I'm trying to parse the login JSON into a Swift 5 object using Codable and then store it in the UserDefaults class, but keep failing miserably and getting the `"Editor placeholder in source file"` error on multiple lines in my login `ViewController`, even though all data is passed correctly (to my best knowledge).

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class Token: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let type: Int?
    let message: String?
    let updateNotifications: UpdateNotifications?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pass: UITextField!

    var name: String?
    var pwd: String?

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

        name = userName.text!
        pwd = pass.text!

        //setting up post requests
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/site/login-data-check")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //setting request headers and body
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let json = [
            "username": name,
            "password": pwd
        ]


        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])

        //making request with URLSessionUploadTask, outputting request data
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in

            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(dataString)


                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let token = try decoder.decode(Token.self, from: data)
                    print(token.token)

                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        //invoking completion handler
        task.resume()        
    }    
}
```